# xpath get the <ul> list element based on non-empty index

Tags: html, css, xpath

```
<ul id="statsArrayRow">
    <li></li>
    <li>19</li>
    <li>44</li>
    <li>48</li>
    <li>35</li>
</ul>
```

In above list, first element has no text content. I want to get element based on non-empty index.
The first non-empty element is 19, second is 44 and so on.

This following xpath returns 19 by index 2 and but i want to get 44 by index 2

```
//ul[@id='statsArrayRow']/li[2])
```

I tried

```
//ul[@id='statsArrayRow' and string-length(text()) > 0]/li[2])
```

It also returns 19 instead of 44.

How can we ignore non-empty element for index?

Answer (score 1):

**Xpath to get 2nd not empty li element:**

```
(//ul[@id='statsArrayRow']/li[string-length(text()) > 0])[2]
```

how it's built:

- `//ul[@id='statsArrayRow']/li` search for all `li` inside ul parent element
- `//ul[@id='statsArrayRow']/li[string-length(text()) > 0]` get `li` elements with text
- `(//ul[@id='statsArrayRow']/li[string-length(text()) > 0])[2]` get 2nd  li with text adding `()[2]` part

**For those who use webdriver + java:**

in java you can get all elements and just filter out empty ones

```
driver.findElements(By.id("statsArrayRow"))
                .stream()
                .filter(e->!e.getText().equals(""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .get(1);
```

Comment: Did i ask how to do in Java? I can also do in PHP or C# but i want xpath